# Sequence of postMessage invocations on iframe

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, iframe

In my main document I had the function showOnMap, which communicated with inner ifame by several postMessage methods. Then I was asked to call the second postMessage only after the first is finished. Is it possible to do this? I have no control over the iframe itself, it comes from an external source. My current code:

```
function showOnMap(record: ITableData) {
  const frame = document.querySelector('iframe') as HTMLIFrameElement;
  if (frame && frame.contentWindow) {
    frame.contentWindow.postMessage(getFirstMessage(record), '*');
    frame.contentWindow.postMessage(getSecondMessage([record]), '*');
  }
}
```

Comment: "to call the second postMessage only after the first is finished"... do you mean the iframe will return some response that you have to wait for?

Comment: no, I was said that it returns nothing